# SSIS - dynamically merging a group of files

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2016

I'm trying to create an import package for our new mssql database and I'm having to merge a group of 20 files together to be fed into a table on the database. However not all of those 20 files will be there every time the import process is run.

However SSIS expects a file to exist so it throws an error. While you can get around the task via a "foreach loop" it only means that the task doesn't run and no merging takes place.

Is there any way around this problem or do I have to do a new task each time I need to merge a new file as that seem kind of unnecessary?

Comment: Have you thought about inporting them into SQL server first, then merging them? That's how I'd do it (im much better with ssms than ssis).